# Formatting an array for json

Tags: php

I'm using FullCalendar jquery plugin to display a calendar on my website. I was able to hardcode some values any it shows up fine on my calendar. The format should be:

```
echo json_encode(array(

        array(
            'id' => 1136,
            'title' => "Understanding Health-Care Regulations (Part II) and COBRA Compliance Strategies",
            'start' => "2011-11-17",
            'url' => "/www/conferences/conference.php?ID=1136"
        ),

        array(
            'id' => 1154,
            'title' => "Making the Most of your Membership",
            'allDay' => false,
            'start' => "Wed, 18 Nov 2011 11:00:00 EST",
            'url' => "/www/conferences/conference.php?ID=1154"
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 1137,
            'title' => "2011 Annual Human Resources Conference",
            'start' => "2011-11-29",
            'url' => "/www/conferences/conference.php?ID=1137"
        ),


    ));
```

When trying to mimic this array structure, I'm using this:

```
$conferences = dbStoredProc('cp_meeting_get_list_new');
$events = array();

foreach ($conferences as $c){
    $push = array(
        'id'        => $c['ID'],
        'title'     => $c['name'],
        'start'     => date("Y", $c['epochDate']) . "-" . date("M", $c['epochDate']) . "-" . date("d", $c['epochDate']),
        'url'       => '/events/details.php?id' . $c['ID'],
    );
    array_push($push, $events);
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

When I echo out my `$events` variable I get `[]`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array_push($push, $events);
```

should be

```
array_push($events, $push);
```

or just

```
$events[] = $push;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just appending the data to the array using

```
$events[] = $push;
```

It's faster, and less confusing than having to look up the order of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As xdazz said, you need to switch the arguments to `array_push`. Alternatively, use the [] syntax to push the item onto the end of the array:

```
$events[] = $push;
```

In addition, you can pass multiple format specifiers to `date`, so your start line can be written as:

```
date("Y-M-d", $c['epochDate']),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is flawed. Try this:

> ```
> $conferences = dbStoredProc('cp_meeting_get_list_new');
> $events = array();
>
> foreach ($conferences as $c){
>    $events[] = array(
>        'id'        => $c['ID'],
>        'title'     => $c['name'],
>        'start'     => date("Y-M-d", $c['epochDate']),
>        'url'       => '/events/details.php?id' . $c['ID']
>     );
> }
> echo json_encode($events);
> ```